# How to duck audio of one app while another plays audio

Tags: windows, audio

I am looking for a way to duck the volume of app `x` when app `y` plays audio. I've tried stuff like routing app `x`'s audio to line 1 and app `y`s audio to line 2, then utilizing ASIO4ALL and FL Studio and using Fruity Limiter to sidechain Line 2 with Line 1, but given the complexity of ASIO4ALL it's hard to pull it off daily. This method also causes audio artifacts, which is not ideal. Any better way to pull this off?